# Issue with .htaccess and 301 redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am currently trying to redirect all my traffic to **https://www**.example.com

I've setup the following code in my .htaccess :

```
#First rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use the correct one (here 
www.)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#Now, rewrite to HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Everything works fine except this scenarios :

If I go to https://example.com/examplepage, I am not redirected to https://**www**.example.com/examplepage

If I go to **http**://example.com/examplepage, I am redirected to **https://**example.com/examplepage and not to https://**www**.example.com/examplepage

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: When I tested your above code on my server, it has worked without issue. First of all, did you clear your cache? Secondly, maybe something is conflicting within your `.htaccess`. Do you have anything else in it?

Comment: I am doing the test in an incognito window.. Only other thing in the .htaccess is the following :

    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress

Comment: Just to clarify the issue is only happening with subdirectories / pages